# Compulsory asterisk in Android TextView

Tags: android, textview

I want to show mandatory fields using `TextView` which includes red colored asterisk

[My Output](https://www.flickr.com/photos/109729836@N08/15741075938/)

[Required Output](https://www.flickr.com/photos/109729836@N08/15741077918/)

I tried modifying the code, but didn't get the expected result.

My Code:

```
public void setCompulsoryAsterisk() {
    txt_name="Name : ";
    String colored="*";
    SpannableStringBuilder strBuilder=new SpannableStringBuilder();
    strBuilder.append(txt_name);
    int start=strBuilder.length();
    strBuilder.append(colored);
    int end=strBuilder.length();
    strBuilder.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    txtName.setText(strBuilder);
}
```

Comment: One should add a comment while downvoting any question. Its a fair practice.
ps - Well downvote was because your question is very easy. Just a small mistake. (I did not downvote, btw)

Comment: I may be easy to u ,but not to me . Hence posted in SO

Comment: @KarthikKolanji did you solved your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String txt_name="Name ";
String colored="*";
String colon = " : ";
```

after you append string colored, append string `colon` after it. Voila.

Comment: The colon too appears in red color.

Comment: Thanks brother it worked .. I use strBuilder1.append(colored);
  int end=strBuilder1.length();
  strBuilder1.append(colon);

Comment: I am glad. Next time, pay attention to code you write, you will avoid many downvotes. :)

Answer (score 4):

Try Something Like This:

```
string = "<font color='#000000'>Name </font>" + "<font color='#FF0000'>*</font>" + "<font color='#000000'>:</font>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(string));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use an unicode to show asterisk in textView like

> `Name* :`

```
<TextView
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Name"/>

<TextView
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="\u002A"
 android:textColor="color/red"/>

<TextView
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text=" :"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example that can be used in `strings.xml`:

```
<resources>
  <string name="app_name">My App\'s Name</string>
  <string name="field_1">Mandatory field<font color='#FF0000'>*</font></string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
String colored="Html.fromHtml(*)";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String simple = "Name";
    String colored = "*";
    String colon = ":";
    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

    builder.append(simple);
    int start = builder.length();
    builder.append(colored);
    int middle = builder.length();

    builder.append(colon);
    int end = builder.length();

    builder.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), start, middle
            ,
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    txt_name.setText(builder);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Below are two ways:**
**1st way:**

```
String  addresstext="Address";
String colored = "*";
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

builder.append(addresstext);
int start = builder.length();
builder.append(colored);
int end = builder.length();

builder.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), start, end,
        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

textviewaddress.setText(builder);
```

**2nd way:**

```
String panNo = "<font color='#000000'>PAN No </font>" + "<font color='#FF0000'>*</font>" + "<font color='#000000'></font>";
textviewpanno_text.setText(Html.fromHtml(panNo));
```